# The Bent Tractrix

Tags: curves, locus

Tangent length between dragged point $P$ and circle lead (instead of straight line of Tractrix) is constant. What is the parameterization of such curves?

This is an attempt  to "bend" the tractrix meridians replacing line of its symmetry by a circular asymptote..  while still maintaining contant tangent length property upto its new bent circle asymptote of radius $R$.

EDIT1

For time being a numerical solution is attempted in self answering mode reporting result obtained so far. It has an upper bent tractrix and a lower tractrix. The lower case results in a shape similar to a cardoid (or spherically reflected rays envelope caustic ) which is briefly presented.

$$ R^2 =  r^2 + a^2 - 2 r a \cos (\pi-\psi) \tag1$$

Arc differentiation gives

$$\tan \psi \cdot \psi '=\left( \frac{1}{a}+\frac{\cos \psi}{r} \right) \tag2 $$

Differential geometric relations in a triangle

$$ r^{'} = \cos \psi; \quad \theta^{'}= \sin \psi/r \tag3 $$

This leads to a property of the bent tractrix:

$$ r\cdot (r+ 2 a \cos \psi) = (R^2-a^2) = R_g^2  \tag4 $$

where the radius of curvature  $CP$ increases rapidly to $R_g $

Constants chosen for drawing are $a=0.6, R=1$.

Bent Tractrix in blue is from CAS. Red tangents are drawn by hand.

The most remarkable property of the Bent Tractrix is its relation to the following well-known property of the Circle with its external or internal power property$ (T^2>0, T^2<0) $ as product of segments from origin is $ r \cdot (r+ 2 a \sin \psi) = T^2 $ that I have not yet fully figured out.. that auxiliary circle has not yet been drawn.

To find center of curvature $C$ and radius of curvature $R_g$ we have the relation

$$\tan {\angle CTP}= \frac{a}{R_g} = \frac{ a+ r \cos \psi}{ r \sin \psi }$$

All comments appreciated.

[image: Two tractrices]

Comment: The symmetry of the problem excludes the angular point you expect.

Comment: @N74 How come it doesn't exclude the angular point on the [_ordinary_ tractrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix)?

Comment: The tractrix is not circular symmetric.

Comment: @N74 So what? True, a straight line does not possess circular symmetry. But it shares one important property with a circle: all its points are exactly equivalent to each other, none is special. How come the tractrix **does** have a special point?

Comment: If you seek a parametric description of a curve, you should give Readers a starting point that is equally rigorous.  Perhaps you have in mind some differential equations that describe a curve with "a circular asymptote"?

Comment: Related (in French): http://www.cabri.net/abracadabri/Courbes/Tract/Tract2b.html

Comment: The start point given is a cusp or angular point already.

Answer (score 0):

The tractrix of a circle is another (smaller) circle whose area is pi.a² smaller than the original; where "a" is the length of the "leash".  Thus, the tractor of a circle does NOT have the original circle as the asymptote.

Comment: Hard to believe, there is an angular point. You are probably referring to the limit cycle.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Hard to believe that the common tractrix (with a cusp) could be a special case of sought out circular tractrix (tractrices?)